# Change the DPI when saving files using Python Image library

Tags: python, image

I'm using the python library Image and cannot save my picture in a higher DPI.

Here is the code:

```
import Image as im 
    import ImageFilter as imf 
    frame = im.new('RGBA', (300,300), "white") 
    c = frame.load() 
    for m in range(0,pylab.size(mutInts)): 
        #Convert the mutation into a colour
        r = make_r(mutInts[m])
        g = make_g(mutInts[m])
        b = make_b(mutInts[m])
        if (type(r) != int):
            r = 150
            print "error: returned r was not an int.. subbing in 150"
        if (type(g) != int):
            g = 150
            print "error: returned g was not an int.. subbing in 150"
        if (type(b) != int):
            b = 150
            print "error: returned b was not an int.. subbing in 150"
        c[int(i[m]),300-int(j[m])] = (r, g, b, 255)

    print frame.size 
    frame = frame.resize([int(3*s) for s in frame.size]) 
    frame = frame.filter(imf.SMOOTH_MORE) 
    picturefilename = newLocation + 'picture_' + filename[:-4] + '.jpg'
    #Save the picture 
    frame.save(picturefilename)
```

I thought frame.save might have a dpi option I could use but I haven't found anything. Any help to control the size and DPI appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at this answer, I think it may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473498/when-printing-an-image-what-determines-how-large-it-will-appear-on-a-page

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize the Python Image Library (PIL) was the same as Image... thanks!